# Optimizing Values that are on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to optimize a PyTorch tensor which I am also using it as input to a network. Lets call this tensor "shape". My optimizer is as follows:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
                        [shape],
                        lr=0.0001
                    )
```

I also am getting vertice values using this "shape" tensor:

```
vertices = model(shape)
```

And my loss function calculates loss as in differences of inferenced vertices and ground truth vertices:

```
loss = torch.sqrt(((gt_vertices - vertices) ** 2).sum(2)).mean(1).mean()
```

So what I am doing is actually estimating shape value. I am only interested in shape values. This works perfectly fine when everything is on CPU. However, when I put my shape and models on GPU by calling `to("cuda")`, I am getting the classic non-leaf Tensor error:

```
ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor
```

Calling `.detach().cpu()` on shape inside optimizer solves the issue, but then gradient's cannot flow as they should be and my values are not updated. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `.to('cuda')`, *e.g.* calling `shape_p = shape.to('cuda')`, you are making a copy of `shape`. While `shape` remains a leaf tensor, `shape_p` is not, because it's 'parent' tensor is `shape`. Therefore `shape_p` is not a leaf and returns the error when trying to optimize it.

Sending it to CUDA device after having set the optimizer, would solve the issue (*there are certain instances when this can't be possible though, [see here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/effect-of-calling-model-cuda-after-constructing-an-optimizer/15165/4)*).

```
>>> optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([shape], lr=0.0001)
>>> shape = shape.cuda()
```

The best option though, in my opinion, is to send it directly on init:

```
>>> shape = torch.rand(1, requires_grad=True, device='cuda')
>>> optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([shape], lr=0.0001)
```

This way it remains a leaf tensor.